# Android AlarmManager starts immediately

Tags: android, sqlite, alarm, notify, vibration

In my database I have a list of date and time in this format "yyyy-mm-dd hh: mm". At each date and time I want to start a corresponding notification. But instead the notification starts immediately. What is wrong?

```
private void setAlarmFromDatabase(){            
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT _id, riserva_3 FROM riserva";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);          
         int count = c.getCount();
            long[] data_ora = new long[count];
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                c.moveToNext();    
                String id = c.getString(0);
                data_ora[i] = c.getLong(1);     

            }

        c.close();
    db.close();

     AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[24];
        for(int ii=0;ii<data_ora.length;ii++)
        {
           alarmManager[ii] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);               

           Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Notifica_scadenza.class);

          PendingIntent displayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),ii,i,0);
          alarmManager[ii].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,(data_ora[ii]), displayIntent);
        }
        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
        }
```

}
The BroadcastReceiver

```
public class Notifica_scadenza extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(1000);
    showNotification(context);
}
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Inserisci_entrate_uscite.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.allarm_icon)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.titolo_scadenza));
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}  
}
```

the permission in the Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver android:name="scad.Notifica_scadenza"></receiver>
```

Comment: AFAIK, SQLite will not magically convert `yyyy-mm-dd hh: mm` into a date that you can use with `getLong()`.

Comment: Also note that `yyyy-mm-dd hh: mm` is not a valid format. You mean `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong, they are in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like CommonsWare mentioned most probably the problem is with the date conversion.
Before the for loop define also a date formatter which you can use to format the received date from the database.

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
```

Now in the for loop try this:

```
try {
    data_ora[i] = dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(1)).getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Something wrong happened while parsing the date.", e);
}
```

You can also log out the data in order to see if the data is correct or not (right after the above line).

```
Log.i("YOUR_TAG", "The id is: " + id + ", and the time: " + data_ora[i]);
```